# How to download apache-mime4j-0.6.1.jar to Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new in the android / eclipse world -

I need to download apache-mime4j-0.6.1.jar to my eclise IDE - 
I don't find anywhere how to do it.

( i need also install it somehow .. ? )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Download link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachemime4j061jar.htm), After download it ,

```
Project -> properties -> java build path -> add external jar -> <select downloaded jar> -> ok
```